# URL with é (e acute)

Tags: android, uri, httpurlconnection, urlencode

I've a problem with a url format. I would like make a get request from the url:
'http://www.radiobébé.com/titre.txt' (http://www.radiobebe.com/titre.txt doesn't exist)

```
String responseBody = "";

    try {
        URL u = new URL("http://www.radiobébé.com/titre.txt");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) u
                .openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        urlConnection.connect();

        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            responseBody = urlConnection.getInputStream().toString();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("RadioBébé", "failed to get song title : " + e.toString());
    }
```

With this function I obtain error 'java.net.UnknownHostException'

I tried:

```
String url = "http://www." + URLencoder.encoder("radiobébé", "UTF-8") + ".com/titre.txt";
```

and

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("http")
    .authority("www.radiobébé.com")
    .appendPath("titre.txt");
```

Same problem.... (host may not be null)

Do you know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, we can use IDN:

```
String url = IDN.toASCII("http://www.radiobébé.com/titre.txt");
```

Result:

url = http://www.xn--radiobb-gyab.com/titre.txt

Answer (score 1):

try this url : http://www.xn--radiobb-gyab.com/titre.txt

When I inspect connections in my browser, this is not http://www.radiobébé.com/titre.txt but this url.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I must use base address, because the redirection can be change